# Trouble getting started with SubSonic

Tags: orm, activerecord, subsonic, domain-driven-design

I have a domain model in my head, and i am having problems building a SubSonic compatible db schema, it would realy help me get started if you could tell me how you would go at it for this example with 3 entities (could be SqlServer OR MySql doesn't matter to me)

**Subject**- representing an educational subject (e.g. Trigonometry, Calculus).
Props- Name

**Technique**- representing a technique used to solve an exercise (e.g. Law of cosines, Pythagorean theorem)
Props- Name, FatherSubject

**Exercise**- representing a certain question.
Props-  Subjects, Techniques (only those used to solve the exercise), DifficultyLevel (enum- easy, meduim, hard), Answer (int).

So:
Many to Many- Exercise -> Subject, Exercise -> Technique 
One to Many- Subject -> Technique.
And DifficultyLevel is an enum.

I'll be sure to contribute to the docs once i'll start to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just build bridge tables between the many-to-many relationships.

```
Table: Subject
Columns: Subject_ID (PK)
         Name (UK)

Table: Technique
Columns: Technique_ID (PK)
         Name (UK)
         Subject_Name (FK)

Table: Exercise
Columns: Exercise_ID (PK)
         Difficulty_ID (FK)
         Question_Text
         Correct_Answer_ID (FK)

Table: Difficulty
Columns: Difficulty_ID (PK)

Table: Exercise_Answer
Columns: Answer_ID (PK)
         Exercise_ID (FK)
         Answer_Text

Table: Exercise_Technique
Columns: Exercise_Technique_ID  (PK)
         Exercise_ID (part of UK, FK)
         Technique_ID (part of UK, FK)
```

- Subject to many Techniques
- Exercise  to many Techniques  (via Exercise_Techniques)
- Exercise to many Answers

By separating out the answers to another table and not using the correct answer ID as a int (as 2nd answer), you can randomize the answers and still know which one is the correct answer by comparing the answer_id value with the exercise.correct_answer_id.

Comment: Thanks for you'r great answer,
I wonder if the convention for the bridge table columns is [table_name1][ID], [table_name2][ID] or [name_of_primary_key1], [name_of_primary_key2], and also what does SubSonic use this convention for? all the doc says is "it will spin some magic for you"...

Comment: None of the above stuff is specific to SubSonic. As long as the relationships are valid, then SubSonic can generate the classes and code for you.

It's just simple database design. It doesn't really matter what you name the columns as long as you're consistent and it's makes somewhat sense to others. I prefer to name my PKs as the tablename_id and then use that same field name for FKs (unless it's something unique like the correct_answer_id which I prefix the fieldname to indicate).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say to use SimpleRepository:
http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository

I'm about to update it with Auto-Migrations for ManyToMany associations which will generate the tables/constraints you need. I'm putting it through it's paces right now so I need a few weeks.

You can email me for the code if you like (without migrations) which is myname @ gmail.

Comment: Hi Rob. I am very interested in how you are going to handle relationships in SimpleRepository! Would I be able to have a class that has a list of another class as a property that is handled by creating a bridge table and associating with each object defentition? Will it handle Update(of ParentObject)(parentObject1) and call delete and update db commands to manage this list?